# unable to import SampleOperation into spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, aggregation-framework

Hi i am trying to import SampleOperation into my class but i am getting unable to import issue however i am able import other Mongo aggregation operationa like MatchOperation or ProjectionOperation.

org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.SampleOperation

[image]

i have tried the latest releases spring data as well, below is a copy of gradle build.

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile ("org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:2.0.4.RELEASE")

compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version: '2.0.4.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-commons', version: '2.0.4.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb', version: '1.5.10.RELEASE'

compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
```

Comment: Just tested on 2.0.4 Release. Works fine for me. Make sure the jar is downloaded. Remove `compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb', version: '1.5.10.RELEASE'` which will bring in lower version spring mongo jar. I've verified in a maven setup.

Comment: Sorry when you said tested on 2.0.4 you mean spring-data-jpa version or spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb version. I even tried the release candidate version  for spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb from here (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb/2.0.0.RC1) but than i get could not resolve all dependencies..would you be able to send the snippet of dependencies where it worked for you. Thanks

Comment: Ok, got it working thanks - i wasn't updating the springBootVersion to '2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'.

Answer (score 1):

Since boot 2.0.0 still not released. It is stated for next week release. So you've to use the RC2 for now. I've used  below maven configuration. Hope you can change into gradle config.

This will download 2.0.4 spring mongo jar.

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb-log4j</artifactId>
   </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.0.RC2</version>
          <type>pom</type>
          <scope>import</scope>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<repositories>
   <repository>
     <id>spring-milestones</id>
     <name>Spring Milestones</name>
     <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
     <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
     </snapshots>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Did the answer help you ? Please consider accepting the answer if did else I will remove the answer.